# Lorentz transformation of the four velocity

Tags: special-relativity

Can we derive the velocity addition rule by directly transforming the four velocity?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: I can't get it. Do we transform the four velocity with the same transformation matrix? I can't even find an example where a four velocity is transformed. (I just started SR. Sorry if my doubts are very trivial)

Answer (score 3):

Theory-wise, the easiest way to use this is to use $w=ct$ and then your Lorentz matrix in 1+1 dimensions can be written as $$\begin{bmatrix}w'\\x'\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\cosh\alpha & -\sinh\alpha\\-\sinh\alpha&\cosh\alpha\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}w\\x\end{bmatrix}.$$
This is because the hyperbolic cosine and sine obey the relation $\cosh^2\alpha - \sinh^2\alpha = 1,$ and therefore if you naturally just choose $\cosh\alpha = 1/\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}$ you naturally find $\sinh^2\alpha = \beta^2/(1 - \beta^2),$ so this is a valid way to write the usual Lorentz Matrix $[\gamma, -\gamma\beta; -\gamma\beta, \gamma].$

Since a 4-velocity in its rest frame is $c~[1; 0]$ it is not hard to see straight from this that a 4-velocity in any other reference frame is $c~[\cosh r; \sinh r]$and therefore that $r = \tanh^{-1}(v/c)$ where $v$ is the ordinary velocity and $r$ is this new quantity called the rapidity. Plugging that in, we can find that it's Lorentz transform is $$\begin{bmatrix}\cosh\alpha & -\sinh\alpha\\-\sinh\alpha&\cosh\alpha\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cosh r\\\sinh r\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\cosh r~\cosh\alpha - \sinh r~\cosh \alpha\\\sinh r~\cosh\alpha-\cosh r~\sinh\alpha\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\cosh (r -
 \alpha)\\\sinh(r-\alpha)\end{bmatrix}.$$So if you transform to its rest frame for example you choose $\alpha=r$ and then the 4-velocity takes this $[c; 0]$ form directly, but rapidities add linearly in one dimension.

Of course for this particular question all of that theory-which-makes-things-simple can be a little bit overkill. If you do not want to use the hyperbolic sines and cosines, you can write this out in terms of the more conventional components as $$\gamma_2\begin{bmatrix}1\\\beta_2\end{bmatrix}= \gamma_0~\gamma_1~\begin{bmatrix}1&-\beta_0\\-\beta_0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\\beta_1\end{bmatrix}.$$
Notice that the noisy prefactors $\gamma_{0,1,2}$ do not need to enter our consciousness at all because the ratio of the second component to the first will be $\gamma_2 \beta_2 / \gamma_2,$ and they will just cancel out on either side So all you're left with when you take this ratio is,$$\beta_2 = \frac{\beta_1 - \beta_0}{1 - \beta_0\beta_1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Instead of the well-known 1-space-dimensional Lorentz Transformation the more general 3-space-dimensional one for the configuration of above Figure (see its 3D version in the end) and with finite variables is<sup>(1)</sup>
\begin{align}                 
 \mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{\prime}} & =  \mathbf{x}+(\gamma_{v}-1)(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}  \mathbf{x})\mathbf{n}+\gamma_{v} \mathbf{v} t 
\tag{01a}\\
 t^{\boldsymbol{\prime}}& =  \gamma_{v}\left( t+\dfrac{\mathbf{v}\boldsymbol{\cdot} \mathbf{x}}{c^{2}}\right)
\tag{01b}      
\end{align}
where
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{n}\equiv \dfrac{\mathbf{v}}{\| \mathbf{v}\| }=\dfrac{\mathbf{v}}{v}\, , \qquad \gamma_{v} = \gamma\left(v\right)\equiv \left(1-\dfrac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)^{-\frac12}
\tag{02}
\end{equation}
and because of linearity with differentials
\begin{align}                 
   \mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{\prime}} & =   \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}+(\gamma_{v}-1)(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot}  \mathrm{d} \mathbf{x})\mathbf{n}+\gamma_{v} \mathbf{v} \mathrm{d} t
\tag{03a}\\
 \mathrm{d} t ^{\boldsymbol{\prime}}& =  \gamma_{v}\left( \mathrm{d} t+\dfrac{\mathbf{v}\boldsymbol{\cdot} \mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}}{c^{2}}\right)
\tag{03b}      
\end{align}
Dividing (03a) by (03b) we have
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{u}^{\boldsymbol{\prime}} = \dfrac{\mathbf{u}+(\gamma_{v}-1)(\mathbf{n}\boldsymbol{\cdot} \mathbf{u})\mathbf{n}+\gamma_{v} \mathbf{v}\vphantom{\dfrac12}}{\gamma_{v} \Biggl(1+\dfrac{\mathbf{v}\boldsymbol{\cdot}  \mathbf{u}}{c^{2}}\Biggr)}
\tag{04}
\end{equation}
Equation (04) is a more general "rule" for the addition of velocities $\mathbf{v},\mathbf{u}$. The 1-dimensional version is the well-known equation 
\begin{equation}
 u^{\boldsymbol{\prime}} = \dfrac{u+v }{1+\dfrac{v\, u}{c^{2}}\vphantom{\dfrac12}}
\tag{05}
\end{equation}
Now, the 4-velocity
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{U} = \left(\gamma_{u}\mathbf{u} ,\gamma_{u} c\right)\, , \qquad \gamma_{u} = \gamma\left(u\right)\equiv \left(1-\dfrac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)^{-\frac12} 
\tag{06}
\end{equation}
as could be proved<sup>(2)</sup>, is a 4-vector : it is Lorentz-transformed as the space-time position vector
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{X} = \left(\mathbf{x} ,c\,t\right)
\tag{07}
\end{equation}

> I don't understand why do you want to reach (04) from the fact that (06) is a 4-vector when inversely this property is a consequence of (04).

---

<sup>(1)
The Lorentz Transformation (01) could be expressed in block matrix form as 
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{X'}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{x'}\vphantom{\dfrac{\gamma \upsilon}{c}\mathbf{n}} \\
\\
c\,t'\vphantom{\dfrac{\gamma \upsilon}{c}\mathbf{n}} 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
         \mathrm{I}+(\gamma_{v}-1)\mathbf{n}\mathbf{n}^{\top} & \dfrac{\gamma_{v} \upsilon}{c}\mathbf{n}\\
        &\\
         \dfrac{\gamma_{v} \upsilon}{c}\mathbf{n}^{\top} &\hspace{5mm}\gamma\\                         
   \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}   
\mathbf{x}\vphantom{\dfrac{\gamma \upsilon}{c}\mathbf{n}} \\
\\
c\,t\vphantom{\dfrac{\gamma \upsilon}{c}\mathbf{n}} 
\end{bmatrix} 
=\Lambda \mathbf{X}
\tag{fn-01}
\end{equation}
where $\:\mathbf{n}\:$ a $\:3\times 1\:$ unit column vector and $\: \mathbf{n}^{\top} \:$ its transposed  $\:1\times 3\:$ unit row vector

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{n}=
\begin{bmatrix}
   n_1\\         
   n_2 \\         
   n_3            
\end{bmatrix}
\quad , \quad
\mathbf{n}^{\top}=
\begin{bmatrix}
  n_1&n_2&n_3
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{fn-02}
\end{equation}
and $\:\mathbf{n}\mathbf{n}^{\top}\:$  a linear transformation, the vectorial projection on the direction $\:\mathbf{n}\:$
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{n}\mathbf{n}^{\top}=
\begin{bmatrix}
   n_1\\         
   n_2 \\         
   n_3            
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  n_1&n_2&n_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
   n_1^{2} & n_1 n_2 & n_1 n_3\\         
   n_2 n_1  & n_2^{2} & n_2 n_3\\          
   n_3 n_1  & n_3 n_2 & n_3^{2}         
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{fn-03}
\end{equation}</sup>

---

<sup>(2)
If a particle is moving with velocity $\mathbf{u}$ with respect to system $\mathrm{S}$ then between its proper time $\tau$ and times $t,t'$ we have
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}\tau}=\gamma_{u}\, , \quad \dfrac{\mathrm{d}t'}{\mathrm{d}\tau}=\gamma_{u'}
\tag{fn-04}
\end{equation}
but from (03b)
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}t'}{\mathrm{d}t}=\gamma_{v} \Biggl(1+\dfrac{\mathbf{v}\boldsymbol{\cdot}  \mathbf{u}}{c^{2}}\Biggr)
\tag{fn-05}
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\gamma_{v} \Biggl(1+\dfrac{\mathbf{v}\boldsymbol{\cdot}  \mathbf{u}}{c^{2}}\Biggr)=\dfrac{\gamma_{u'}}{\gamma_{u}}
\tag{fn-06}
\end{equation}
Replacing this in the dominator of the rhs of (04) we note that the quantities $\gamma_{u}\mathbf{u}$ and $\gamma_{u}$ are transformed as  $\mathbf{x}$ and $t$ in equations (01), that is finally
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{U'}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma_{u'}\mathbf{u'}\vphantom{\dfrac{\gamma \upsilon}{c}\mathbf{n}} \\
\\
\gamma_{u'}c\vphantom{\dfrac{\gamma \upsilon}{c}\mathbf{n}} 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
         \mathrm{I}+(\gamma_{v}-1)\mathbf{n}\mathbf{n}^{\top} & \dfrac{\gamma_{v} \upsilon}{c}\mathbf{n}\\
        &\\
         \dfrac{\gamma_{v} \upsilon}{c}\mathbf{n}^{\top} &\hspace{5mm}\gamma\\                         
   \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}   
\gamma_{u}\mathbf{u}\vphantom{\dfrac{\gamma \upsilon}{c}\mathbf{n}} \\
\\
\gamma_{u}c\vphantom{\dfrac{\gamma \upsilon}{c}\mathbf{n}} 
\end{bmatrix} 
=\Lambda \mathbf{U}
\tag{fn-07}
\end{equation}</sup>

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. You just have to use the definition. Don't get lost in the Minkowski space; velocity is the time derivative of the position.

If you derive the expression

$x'=\gamma (x-vt)$

you will finally obtain the transformations of velocities; but be careful, because deriving respect to $t$ is not the same as doing so with $t'$. You have to apply the chain rule. The development is done in books, like Alonso-Finn.

Of course this is not the only way to get them. Using the parameters so that

$v/c=\tanh \zeta$, then the addition formula is directly obtained as the sum of two $\tanh$'s.

Comment: Thanks! I have seen this approach, but I was wondering how to directly perform lorentz transformation on the four velocity. What is the transformation matrix in that case? Do we have to find it by taking the deivative after all?